# What does the URL argument do in the xhr.open() function?

Tags: html, node.js, server, xmlhttprequest

I am writing some server software, and I have tested it using a very simple HTML file. It doesn't seem to make any difference what the URL argument is when I open a new XMLHttpRequest POST request. Can anyone tell me? Here is the code if it helps:

Browser HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <title>This is a title!</title>
        <p id="paragraph">
            Hello World!
        </p>
        <script>
            setTimeout(() => {
                var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
                var jsonToSend = {
                    "name": "Steve Smith",
                    "age": 25,
                    "isMale": true
                };
                http.open("POST", "", true);
                http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                http.send(JSON.stringify(jsonToSend));
            }, 3000);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Server code (node.js)

```
const http = require("http");
const fs = require("fs");
const port = 80;

http.createServer((request, response) => {
    if (request.method == "GET") {
        try {
            var newUrl = request.url.substring(1);

            if (request.url == "/") {
                newUrl = "test.html";
            }

            response.writeHead(200, "OK", {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
            response.write(fs.readFileSync(newUrl).toString());
        } catch (error) {
            response.writeHead(404, "Not Found", {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
            response.write("<h1>404 not found</h1>");
        }
        response.end();
    } else if (request.method == "POST") {
        var body = "";

        request.on("data", (chunk) => {
            body += chunk.toString();
        });
        request.on("end", () => {
            console.log(JSON.parse(body));
            response.statusCode = 200;
            response.end(body);
        });
    }

    console.log(request.method + ":");
    console.log("  URL: " + request.url);
    console.log("  Status code: " + response.statusCode);
}).listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Listening on port " + port);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sets the URL the request is made to.

It only doesn't seem to make a difference because you're written a webserver which *doesn't pay attention to the URL* for POST requests.

Comment: Ah ok! But what would be the point of it on a normal web browser? I thought that the browser is simply telling the server some information, how a URL is needed in that process?

Comment: Most web applications are sufficiently complex that that need to be told multiple things in different contexts. Amazon, for instance, expects people to post data to create an account, to log in, to add to a shopping basket, to place an order, to submitted credit card details, and so on.

Comment: Oh ok. I see. So does the URL of the post request specify which file the server will write the data to, for example?

Comment: No. It just identifies the resource that handles the request.

Comment: Oh ok, I understand now! Thanks very much for your help.